# static libqxt - missing anything?

Tags: qt, static, qt-creator, static-linking, libqxt

OK, to sum it up... There's probably a config problem with STATIC Qxt on windows. It should link against libcrypto.a and libssl.a, but it doesn't, making any program trying to staticaly compile against qxtnetwork fail with missing references...

With current Qxt source I am unable to compile static binary of my project from Qt Creator, because of missing references to libcrypto.a

I CAN compile the piece of software manually, adding -lcrypto and -lgdi32 to the end of command line generated by Qt Creator:

```
C:\Dev\Projekty\apps_src\MakeAHole-static>g++ -enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,windows -o release\MakeAHole.exe object_script.MakeAHole.Release  -LC:/Qt/static/lib -lmingw32 -lqtmain -lQxtGui -lQxtNetwork -lQxtCore -lQtGui -lQtNetwork -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -loleaut32 -limm32 -lwinmm -lwinspool -lmsimg32 -lQtCore -lkernel32 -luser32 -lshell32 -luuid -lole32 -ladvapi32 -lcrypto -lssl -lws2_32 -lgdi32
```

And here's the whole story:

Was anyone able to use static version of libqxt? I have properly prepared static Qt and Qxt. Alas - it seems a proper object to link against libssh part of qxtnetwork fails. Compiling my program fails with missing references to various openssl functons.

And here's my configure line:

```
configure.bat -qmake-bin C:\Qt\static\bin\qmake.exe -release -prefix C:\Qt\static -static -no-db -I C:\mingw\include -I C:\mingw\include\openssl -L C:\Qt\static\lib -l crypto -l ssl -l ws2_32
```

(note that openssl manual says:

> libcrypto.a and libssl.a are the static libraries. To use the DLLs,
>   link with libeay32.a and libssl32.a instead.

), so I am not using ssl32 and eay32.

Note taht openssl.pro in Qxt has following line - maybe they cause the problem?

```
!win32:LIBS+= -lcrypto -lssl
```

and libssh2.pri such lines:

```
!win32:!symbian{
  INCLUDEPATH +=  $$PWD/linux
  LIBS+=-lcrypto -lz
}
```

All needed libraries are at proper a place, namely c:\qt\static\lib\

Mind that I am using dynamic version of Qxt compiled without "-static" into different directory, and that one works without a problem.

Then I do

```
mingw32-make
mingw32-make install
```

and try to compile using Qt Creator:

```
Running build steps for project MakeAHole...
Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
Starting: "C:\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
c:\qt\static\bin\qmake.exe -spec ..\..\..\..\Qt\static\mkspecs\win32-g++ CONFIG+=release -o Makefile ..\MakeAHole\MakeAHole.pro
C:/mingw/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Dev/Projekty/apps_src/MakeAHole-static'
g++ -enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,windows -o release\MakeAHole.exe object_script.MakeAHole.Release  -L"c:\Qt\static\lib" -lmingw32 -lqtmain -lcrypto -lssl -LC:/Qt/static/lib -lQxtGui -lQxtNetwork -lQxtCore -lQtGui -lQtNetwork -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -loleaut32 -limm32 -lwinmm -lwinspool -lmsimg32 -lQtCore -lkernel32 -luser32 -lshell32 -luuid -lole32 -ladvapi32 -lws2_32 
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Dev/Projekty/apps_src/MakeAHole-static'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(knownhost.o):knownhost.c:(.text+0x5d2): undefined reference to `EVP_sha1'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(knownhost.o):knownhost.c:(.text+0x5f2): undefined reference to `HMAC_Init'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(knownhost.o):knownhost.c:(.text+0x61e): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(knownhost.o):knownhost.c:(.text+0x63b): undefined reference to `HMAC_Final'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(knownhost.o):knownhost.c:(.text+0x649): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_cleanup'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(channel.o):channel.c:(.text+0x1b5e): undefined reference to `RAND_bytes'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(hostkey.o):hostkey.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `DSA_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(hostkey.o):hostkey.c:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `EVP_get_digestbyname'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(hostkey.o):hostkey.c:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(hostkey.o):hostkey.c:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(hostkey.o):hostkey.c:(.text+0xc5): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(hostkey.o):hostkey.c:(.text+0x171): undefined reference to `DSA_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(hostkey.o):hostkey.c:(.text+0x1ca): undefined reference to `DSA_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(hostkey.o):hostkey.c:(.text+0x2ce): undefined reference to `RSA_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(hostkey.o):hostkey.c:(.text+0x2fc): undefined reference to `EVP_get_digestbyname'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(hostkey.o):hostkey.c:(.text+0x30b): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(hostkey.o):hostkey.c:(.text+0x326): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(hostkey.o):hostkey.c:(.text+0x343): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(hostkey.o):hostkey.c:(.text+0x3c1): undefined reference to `RSA_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(hostkey.o):hostkey.c:(.text+0x41a): undefined reference to `RSA_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(transport.o):transport.c:(.text+0x8e8): undefined reference to `RAND_bytes'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(global.o):global.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xda): undefined reference to `BN_CTX_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xf0): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xfb): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x13f): undefined reference to `BN_rand'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x166): undefined reference to `BN_mod_exp'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x174): undefined reference to `BN_num_bits'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x190): undefined reference to `BN_num_bits'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x1ea): undefined reference to `BN_num_bits'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x219): undefined reference to `BN_bn2bin'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x391): undefined reference to `EVP_get_digestbyname'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x3a0): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x3b6): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x3cd): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x3d9): undefined reference to `EVP_get_digestbyname'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x3e5): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x3fb): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x412): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x47f): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x4c0): undefined reference to `BN_mod_exp'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x4cb): undefined reference to `BN_num_bits'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x4e7): undefined reference to `BN_num_bits'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x535): undefined reference to `BN_num_bits'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x564): undefined reference to `BN_bn2bin'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x570): undefined reference to `EVP_get_digestbyname'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x585): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x5c4): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x60f): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x62a): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x663): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x688): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x6b1): more undefined references to `EVP_DigestUpdate' follow
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x865): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xa3c): undefined reference to `EVP_get_digestbyname'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xa48): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xa61): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xa78): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xa9d): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xab3): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xacc): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xaef): undefined reference to `EVP_get_digestbyname'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xafb): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xb14): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xb2b): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xb50): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xb66): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xb7f): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xc57): undefined reference to `EVP_get_digestbyname'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xc63): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xc7c): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xc93): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xcb8): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xcce): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xce7): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xd0a): undefined reference to `EVP_get_digestbyname'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xd16): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xd2f): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xd46): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xd6b): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xd81): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xd9a): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xe9b): undefined reference to `EVP_get_digestbyname'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xea7): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xec0): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xed7): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xefc): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xf12): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xf2b): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xfd3): undefined reference to `EVP_get_digestbyname'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xfdf): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0xff8): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x100f): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x1034): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x104a): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x1063): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x1163): undefined reference to `BN_clear_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x1178): undefined reference to `BN_clear_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x118a): undefined reference to `BN_clear_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x119c): undefined reference to `BN_clear_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x11ae): undefined reference to `BN_CTX_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x1380): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x138b): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x13a1): undefined reference to `BN_set_word'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x13bf): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x141d): undefined reference to `BN_clear_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x1435): undefined reference to `BN_clear_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x1467): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x1472): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x15d5): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x1601): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x1674): undefined reference to `BN_clear_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x168c): undefined reference to `BN_clear_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x16b4): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x16bf): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x16d5): undefined reference to `BN_set_word'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x16f3): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x1757): undefined reference to `BN_clear_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x176f): undefined reference to `BN_clear_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(kex.o):kex.c:(.text+0x1ef3): undefined reference to `RAND_bytes'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `BIO_new_file'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `BIO_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `BN_bn2bin'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x149): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_get_app_data'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x270): undefined reference to `EVP_aes_256_ecb'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x2a5): undefined reference to `EVP_EncryptInit'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x2be): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x2df): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_app_data'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x302): undefined reference to `RSA_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x30b): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x329): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x330): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x34e): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x35d): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x378): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x37f): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x39d): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x3a4): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x3c2): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x3c9): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x3e7): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x3ee): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x40c): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x413): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x431): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x44f): undefined reference to `DSA_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x458): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x476): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x47d): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x49b): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x4a2): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x4c0): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x4c7): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x4e5): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x4f0): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x50b): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x527): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x54b): undefined reference to `EVP_CipherInit'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x588): undefined reference to `EVP_Cipher'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x5e2): undefined reference to `PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x611): undefined reference to `PEM_read_bio_DSAPrivateKey'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x639): undefined reference to `RSA_size'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x67b): undefined reference to `RSA_sign'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x6c7): undefined reference to `DSA_do_sign'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x6de): undefined reference to `BN_num_bits'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x6fd): undefined reference to `BN_num_bits'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x714): undefined reference to `DSA_SIG_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x739): undefined reference to `BN_bn2bin'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x751): undefined reference to `BN_bn2bin'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x759): undefined reference to `DSA_SIG_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x778): undefined reference to `EVP_get_digestbyname'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x787): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x79d): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x7b4): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x7c9): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x7e0): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x7e5): undefined reference to `BN_new'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x7ff): undefined reference to `BN_bin2bn'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x836): undefined reference to `DSA_do_verify'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x843): undefined reference to `BN_clear_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x84e): undefined reference to `BN_clear_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x8aa): undefined reference to `RSA_verify'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x8cb): undefined reference to `EVP_get_digestbyname'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x8da): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestInit'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x8f0): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x907): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x92c): undefined reference to `BIO_new_file'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x948): undefined reference to `EVP_get_cipherbyname'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x951): undefined reference to `OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x971): undefined reference to `BIO_ctrl'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x990): undefined reference to `PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x99b): undefined reference to `BIO_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0x9e4): undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0xa12): undefined reference to `BN_num_bits'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0xa2c): undefined reference to `BN_num_bits'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0xa9d): undefined reference to `RSA_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0xaee): undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get1_DSA'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0xb1c): undefined reference to `BN_num_bits'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0xb36): undefined reference to `BN_num_bits'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0xb4b): undefined reference to `BN_num_bits'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0xb60): undefined reference to `BN_num_bits'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0xbf0): undefined reference to `DSA_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0xc6b): undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0xc7d): undefined reference to `RSA_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(openssl.o):openssl.c:(.text+0xc91): undefined reference to `DSA_free'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(crypt.o):crypt.c:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(crypt.o):crypt.c:(.rdata+0xbc): undefined reference to `EVP_aes_256_cbc'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(crypt.o):crypt.c:(.rdata+0xfc): undefined reference to `EVP_aes_256_cbc'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(crypt.o):crypt.c:(.rdata+0x12c): undefined reference to `EVP_aes_192_cbc'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(crypt.o):crypt.c:(.rdata+0x15c): undefined reference to `EVP_aes_128_cbc'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(crypt.o):crypt.c:(.rdata+0x190): undefined reference to `EVP_bf_cbc'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(crypt.o):crypt.c:(.rdata+0x1c0): undefined reference to `EVP_rc4'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(crypt.o):crypt.c:(.rdata+0x1ec): undefined reference to `EVP_rc4'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(crypt.o):crypt.c:(.rdata+0x21c): undefined reference to `EVP_cast5_cbc'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(crypt.o):crypt.c:(.rdata+0x24c): undefined reference to `EVP_des_ede3_cbc'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `EVP_ripemd160'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `HMAC_Init'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0xfb): undefined reference to `HMAC_Final'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0x103): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_cleanup'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0x139): undefined reference to `EVP_md5'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0x15c): undefined reference to `HMAC_Init'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0x192): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0x1b0): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0x1cd): undefined reference to `HMAC_Final'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0x1d5): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_cleanup'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0x262): undefined reference to `EVP_sha1'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0x285): undefined reference to `HMAC_Init'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0x29f): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0x2bb): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0x2d9): undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0x2f6): undefined reference to `HMAC_Final'
c:\Qt\static\lib/libQxtNetwork.a(mac.o):mac.c:(.text+0x2fe): undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_cleanup'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release\MakeAHole.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
The process "C:\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project MakeAHole (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

Following lines exist in my *.pro file:

```
win32:LIBS += -lcrypto
win32:LIBS += -lssl
win32:LIBS += -lws2_32
```

Answer (score 0):

to work with openssl you need generally two libs: `libeay32` and `ssleay32`. find them and write right paths to them in your win32:LIBS

Comment: Install Openssl says:    

libcrypto.a and libssl.a are the static libraries. To use the DLLs, link with libeay32.a and libssl32.a instead.

Comment: interesting... when you call to g++ there is no ssl libs in lib list passing there.

Comment: also, `Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.` in your listing - are you sure you have your makefile regenerated? Look at the seventh line of your listing to see what libs really being linked...

Comment: OK, changed win32:LIBS entries, look at this line again. Now they appear there...

Comment: I tried to compile it manually. When I add -lcrypto AT THE end of g++ command line the compilation complains only about: 
C:/Qt/static/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xa0c): undefined ref
erence to `CreateDCA@16'
C:/Qt/static/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xa70): undefined ref
erence to `GetObjectA@12'
C:/Qt/static/lib/libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c:(.text+0xaeb): undefined ref
erence to `GetBitmapBits@12'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Ha! And it compiles succesfully whit -lcrypto -lgdi32 added at the very end of command line. But how can I add it in Qt Creator?

Comment: if to look https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com//browse/QTBUG-5873 - they say that `specifically "-lgdi32" must appear after "-lssl -lcypto" when linking otherwise executables will fail to link with something like: libcrypto.a(rand_win.o):rand_win.c::-1: error: undefined reference to `GetBitmapBits@12'`

Comment: into PRO file - look in which order libs appears... try to find all -lgdi32 and place them in the very end of PRO file

Comment: Yeah - but that still leaves me with my project NOT compiling from Qt Creator, as it compiles ONLY when -lcrypto is at end of command line, just before -lgdi32. But when added in .pro file it appears somewhere in the middle of command line. Shouln't libcrypto be linked staticaly to Qxt at static-Qxt build time instead?

Comment: you may try that. I don't know, but if QExt use it that would be right approach...

Comment: also, if it will be linked there you will need to do all this magic with command line once instead of every rebuild of your own project.

Comment: Exactly, but I guess it's up to Qxt team to fix it. Makefiles are like black magic to me.